# Observable array value is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js. I have an obeservable array whose value are shown in a list form. Now i am trying to update the array value. The value is updating when we first click edit link but  after that instead of showing value the `whole function text shows`:

http://jsbin.com/ihucep/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the **ceremony** object passed to function **editCeremony** is an observable and should be called as a function to get its value: **ceremony()** instead of **ceremony**

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ihucep/4/edit